# JBoss AS 7 configuration

Tags: configuration, jboss7.x

I downloaded JBoss AS 7 and trying to run my application in it. But I couldn't find `server.xml` to change settings. Previously I used `JBoss AS 4.2.2` and have `server.xml` in `<jboss_home>\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer`. Can anyone help me how to configure AS 7?

Comment: what is the exact setting you want to set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory layout has changed. See here: 
  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide

Most of the stuff is in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml or the "domain/**" folders depending on which config/server you are running.

If you want to configure the web container specifically then see here:
  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Containerconfiguration

..and modify the standalone.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid touching the config XMLs yourself.
Rather let it up to domain controller and host controller.

JBoss AS 7 has many ways to be managed.
At least these are those I know of:

1. Programatical:

   - CLI - bash-like command-line tool,
   - Java API - a Java JAR with remoting, you simply call methods.
   - REST-like API - you send commands over HTTP.

     - JBoss AS 7 Management API docs:
       https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+API+reference
2. User Interface:

   - Administration Console, see http://localhost:9990/console (by default)
   - RHQ project

     - See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+Clients

Current location of emerging JBoss AS 7 Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Documentation